# Python pandas data frame warning, suggest to use .loc instead?

Tags: python-2.7, indexing, pandas

Hi I would like to manipulate the data by removing missing information and make all letters lower case. But for the lowercase conversion, I get this warning:

```
E:\Program Files Extra\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py:1808: UserWarning: Boolean Series key will be reindexed to match DataFrame index.
  "DataFrame index.", UserWarning)
C:\Users\KubiK\Desktop\FamSeach_NameHandling.py:18: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
```

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
`frame3["name"] = frame3["name"].str.lower()`

```
C:\Users\KubiK\Desktop\FamSeach_NameHandling.py:19: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
```

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  `frame3["ethnicity"] = frame3["ethnicity"].str.lower()`

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame

# Get csv file into data frame
data = pd.read_csv("C:\Users\KubiK\Desktop\OddNames_sampleData.csv")
frame = DataFrame(data)
frame.columns = ["name", "ethnicity"]
name = frame.name
ethnicity = frame.ethnicity

# Remove missing ethnicity data cases
index_missEthnic = frame.ethnicity.isnull()
index_missName = frame.name.isnull()
frame2 = frame[index_missEthnic != True]
frame3 = frame2[index_missName != True]

# Make all letters into lowercase
frame3["name"] = frame3["name"].str.lower()
frame3["ethnicity"] = frame3["ethnicity"].str.lower()

# Test outputs
print frame3
```

This warning doesn't seem to be fatal (at least for my small sample data), but how should I deal with this?

**Sample data**

```
Name    Ethnicity
Thos C. Martin                              Russian
Charlotte Wing                              English
Frederick A T Byrne                         Canadian
J George Christe                            French
Mary R O'brien                              English
Marie A Savoie-dit Dugas                    English
J-b'te Letourneau                           Scotish
Jane Mc-earthar                             French
Amabil?? Bonneau                            English
Emma Lef??c                                 French
C., Akeefe                                  African
D, James Matheson                           English
Marie An: Thomas                            English
Susan Rrumb;u                               English
                                            English
Kaio Chan
```

Comment: I'm curious if you read the caveats that the warning suggested. How did they fail in answering this question for you?

Comment: I did read the caveats. It is an over-simplified sample which is not useful for new programmers like myself. And even when I follow experienced programmers' suggestions of using .loc, same warnings persist (as below).

Comment: the example is very similar to yours in my opinion. In the answer below, you're still assigning with a copy -- `loc` in on the wrong side in other words. See my comment on that post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you set frame2/3, trying using .loc as follows:

```
frame2 = frame.loc[~index_missEthnic, :]
frame3 = frame2.loc[~index_missName, :]
```

I think this would fix the error you're seeing:

```
frame3.loc[:, "name"] = frame3.loc[:, "name"].str.lower()
frame3.loc[:, "ethnicity"] = frame3.loc[:, "ethnicity"].str.lower()
```

You can also try the following, although it doesn't answer your question:

```
frame3.loc[:, "name"] = [t.lower() if isinstance(t, str) else t for t in frame3.name]
frame3.loc[:, "ethnicity"] = [t.lower() if isinstance(t, str) else t for t in frame3. ethnicity]
```

This converts any string in the column into lowercase, otherwise it leaves the value untouched.

Comment: Thanks I did what you suggested, but there are still warning messages as below

Comment: C:\Users\KubiK\Desktop\FamSeach_NameHandling.py:18: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  frame3["name"] = frame3["name"].str.lower()
C:\Users\KubiK\Desktop\FamSeach_NameHandling.py:19: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

Comment: See the the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  frame3["ethnicity"] = frame3["ethnicity"].str.lower()

Comment: @KubiK888:  BTW, it helps to provide some sample data so that users can play around with it (vs. a csv file on your computer).

Comment: I have tried your second set of suggestion, but the same warning persists.

Comment: I think it should be e.g., `frame3.loc[:, "name"] = frame3["name"].str.lower()`

Comment: @Alexander you're still assigning to a copy. I think you should edit your answer to reflect my comment above so that future readers don't have to scroll through all of these comments.

Comment: @PaulH Yes, I will amend my response and include a more lengthy discussion on the topic but won't have time to address it for a couple of days.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure why do you need so many booleans...
Also note that `.isnull()` does not catch empty strings.
And filtering empty string before applying `.lower()` doesn't seems neccessary either.
But it there is a need... This works for me:

```
frame = pd.DataFrame({'name':['Abc Def', 'EFG GH', ''], 'ethnicity':['Ethnicity1','', 'Ethnicity2']})
print frame

    ethnicity     name
0  Ethnicity1  Abc Def
1               EFG GH
2  Ethnicity2         

name_null = frame.name.str.len() == 0
frame.loc[~name_null, 'name'] = frame.loc[~name_null, 'name'].str.lower()
print frame

    ethnicity     name
0  Ethnicity1  abc def
1               efg gh
2  Ethnicity2
```