# Warning: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

Tags: pandas

I have this DataFrame:

```
               Pred
Date               
2002-03-01 -0.03729
2002-04-01  0.11047
2002-05-01  0.02842
2002-06-01  0.01005
2002-07-01 -0.03607
2002-08-01  0.07484
...
```

I'm using the following function:

```
def lag(df):
    df.columns=['Value']
    df.sort_index(ascending=True)

    df['1lag']=df.Value.shift(1)
    df['2lag']=df.Value.shift(2)
    df['3lag']=df.Value.shift(3)
    df['4lag']=df.Value.shift(4)
```

And it keeps giving me the same warning:

```
See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
df['1lag']=df.Value.shift(1)
/Users/file.py:1020: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
```

It is coming out one warning for each of the df.Value.shift commands.
Any ideas why is it happening?

Comment: this is a common issue, try searching that text from the error and see some of the solutions. Here's one possible solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29263506/python-pandas-data-frame-warning-suggest-to-use-loc-instead?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
def lag(df):
    df.columns=['Value']
    df.sort_index(ascending=True)

    df = df.assign(lag1=df.Value.shift(1))
    df = df.assign(lag2=df.Value.shift(2))
    df = df.assign(lag3=df.Value.shift(3))
    df = df.assign(lag4=df.Value.shift(4))
    return df
```

Comment: What do you do if you need the column names to have spaces in them?

Comment: @CS Such as `df['Some Value'].shift(1)`? Or `df.assign(some_lag=df.Value.shift(1)`?  The latter case requires replacing spaces with a character such as the underscore.